# Prediction of constants with the standard model

Tags: experimental-physics, standard-model, physical-constants, data

I am trying to understand how the standard model predicts constants.
Does it also predict fundamental constants such as the mass of the electron?

And when looking at the result of the $g-2$ experiment, I noticed that the theoretical prediction of the constant is not a single value  but a small range of values and so:

Are some/all of the constants believed to have a range of values?

Comment: 1. The SM accommodates $m_e$, etc.., by using its experimental value  to specify the respective Yukawa coupling, a "fundamental" parameter of it. 2. In a perfect calculation, there would be no range; but there is so much slop and calculational "best guesses" and shortcuts, as well as slop in the parameters of the SM used, that the likely systematic error is quantified in a range.

Answer (score 1):

The [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) (SM) of particle physics has a large number of constants axiomatically, all the values characterizing the particles and antiparticles in the table

[image]

are taken as given for the quantum field theory calculations of the SM, the mass of the electron included.

A large number of other constants can be calculated once there is a SM and the tools of quantum field theory, which then can be checked against data and if there is a disagreement  new physics is indicated.

[The g-2 experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon_g-2) is one of these numbers:

> Muon g-2  is a particle physics experiment at Fermilab to measure the anomalous magnetic dipole moment of a muon to a precision of 0.14 ppm,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) which will be a sensitive test of the Standard Model. It might also provide evidence of the existence of entirely new particles

Anomalous means the measured magnetic dipole moment of the muon disagrees with the calculated one using the SM.

Comment: Isn't the anomalous magnetic dipole moment the disagreement between $g$ and its classical prediction (ie $g=2$) rather than the SM calculated one?

Comment: @jacob1729  g=2 it is the Dirac equation one,  and they "call it classical"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon_g-2 . I would think that the standard model is based on the Dirac equation solutions for its fermions.

Comment: The Dirac equation is classical in the sense I intended. The SM calculation includes many Feynman diagrams and $g=2$ is the result of the "classical" (that is, tree level) diagrams. The anomalous moment is then due to the loops. I think the theoretical uncertainty is just due to the nature of perturbation theory - we don't know how large the loop diagrams we haven't computed are, so there is some uncertainty.

Comment: @jacob1729 and a window for evidence of new physics if it disagrees with the higher loop calculations of the SM, thus the experiments